# Associate Protractor with TFS (MTM)

Tags: angularjs, tfs, protractor, microsoft-test-manager

I was wondering whether it is possible to connect my protractor tests with TFS and run it from Microsoft Test Manager.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integration will be very limited. You can create a Generic Test in Visual Studio and associate that to your Test Case in MTM. The Generic Test can run the actual commandline that will trigger Protractor.

The only test runner that can currently directly integrate into MTM is MsTest, any other test runner needs to be wrapped by a Generic Test in order to integrate into MTM.

Answer (score 1):

In previous engagements with customers i have used a T4 template to generate MS Test stubs for each of my tests in an unsupported third party tool. I then use the MTM command line tool to import the generated Tests as Test Cases in MTM. Then you can run them against an environment.